# GCP Cloud Run Job with custom command can't find scripts in WORKDIR

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run

Trying to create two GCP cloud run jobs based on the same docker image, just different commands. I can run the jobs locally using Docker, but when I try and create cloud run jobs on GCP they fail to find the scripts placed in the WORKDIR defined in the Dockerfile. E.g.

```
#Dockerfile
WORKDIR /app
COPY script1.py .
COPY script2.py .
```

On my local machine:

```
docker build -t image .
docker run image python3 script1.py
docker run image python3 script2.py
```

Both work fine. But if I deploy as cloud run jobs:

```
    gcloud beta run jobs deploy job1 \
    image=path-to-image:latest \
    --region=region\
    --command="/usr/bin/python3 script1.py"
```

Fails with:

```
terminated: Application failed to start: invalid status ::14: could not start container: 
no such file or directory
```

Note, I seem to need `/usr/bin/python3` on cloud run even though `python3` is on the path running a docker container locally.

I have tried:

```
--command="/usr/bin/python3 script1.py"
--command="/usr/bin/python3 script1.py /app/script1.py" 
--command="/usr/bin/python3./script1.py"
```

All fail to find the scripts when running as a cloud run job. Anyone know how to make custom commands work correctly with WORKDIR?

Comment: Are you sure about your Python absolute path?

Comment: Yes. The problem I found was that you need to split the command and it's arguments, e.g. 

    --command=/usr/bin/python3
    --args=script1.py

Comment: Answer your own question with the solution. It could help others

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Christian is correct, but for completeness I'm showing custom command and args to the job. The thing that confused me (should have realized) is that a *command cannot contain spaces*, i.e. it really must be a command, not a command + args. So pass the command and args separately.

```
# Dockerfile
WORKDIR /app 
COPY script1.py . 
COPY script2.py . 
#CMD whatever, we will override it
```

To deploy equivalent jobs on GCP:

```
gcloud beta run jobs deploy job1 \
    --image=path-to-image:latest \
    --region=region\
    --command="/usr/bin/python3"
    --args="script1.py"

gcloud beta run jobs deploy job2 \
    --image=path-to-image:latest \
    --region=region\
    --command="/usr/bin/python3"
    --args="script2.py"
```

Answer (score 1):

Cloud Run overrides the CMD used in the Dockerfile when a custom command is specified in the `gcloud beta run jobs` deploy command. In your situation, this means that you must explicitly specify the path of the script because the python3 command is not run by default.

Docker

```
WORKDIR /app 
COPY script1.py . 
COPY script2.py . 
CMD ["python3", "script1.py"]
```

Then, in the gcloud beta run jobs deploy command, you can pass the path to the script as an argument:

Sample:

```
gcloud beta run jobs deploy job1 image=path-to-image:latest --region=region --args="/app/script1.py"
```